# Rails 5 Dynamically Load Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a basic Rails app that currently has two models, Payperiod and Expense. A Payperiod has many Expenses, and an expense belongs to one Payperiod. I have my expenses resourced nested under payperiods, like so:

`resources :payperiods do
    resources :expenses
  end`

I am attempting to create an expense on the Payperiod show page. Ideally, I'd like to have a button for adding individual expenses. This is turning out to be trickier than I thought it would be. I know I need to use ajax to dynamically add the form for each expense and submit it but I can't figure out exactly how to make it work. In my Payperiod `show.html.erb` page I have a button with an id that I can click and make an action happen via jquery. My next step is to make this button render a form. I'm not sure if I can do this via jquery inside of an `html.erb` file, or if I should convert my payperiod show view to be `show.js.erb`.